# Difficulty printing fancyhdr and margin specification

Tags: fancyhdr, printing

I'm trying to print a calendar, hedge to hedge, bottom to top.
So I used the fancyhdr packages and put all the specified margins and it look great, but when I get the PDF and use the printing dialogue, things get messy.

I have the choice -> fit to page or not

But since I want the calendar to use the most space possible on the page (once printed) if I un-check the "fit to page" option things go off the page.

How do I print as big as possible.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %                                                                          
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %   Load a font with all the characters                                  
%
\usepackage{lmodern}        %                                                                   
%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{nofooter}{%
\fancyfoot{}%
}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calendar} % Use the calendar.sty style

\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.6in,top=0.1in,bmargin=0.01in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes the page number from the bottom of the page

\noindent

\StartingDayNumber=1 % Calendar starting day, default of 1 means Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc


\newpage

\begin{center}
\textsc{\Huge Octobre}\\ % Month
\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\noindent
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{calendar}{\hsize}


\setcounter{calendardate}{28} % Start the date counter at 1

 % 1 - Example of content
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\setcounter{calendardate}{1}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}
\day{}{\vspace{3.1cm}}


\setcounter{calendardate}{1}
\day{}{\vspace{2.9cm}}

\finishCalendar
\end{calendar}
\end{flushleft}
```

for calendar.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\def\CalendarVersion{3.1}
\def\CalendarVersionDate{2009/04/24}

\ProvidesClass{calendar}[\CalendarVersionDate
       LaTeX2e class file `calendar' v\CalendarVersion]

\typeout{'calendar' style \CalendarVersion \CalendarVersionDate.}
\typeout{Created by Evan Sultanik}
\typeout{****** Bugs/comments/suggestions/technicalities to Evan Sultanik -- evan@sultanik.com ******}

\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\def\@CALtrue{1}
\newcount\@currentdaynum
\newcounter{calendardate}
\newcount\StartingDayNumber

\def\dayheader#1#2{
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.87\hsize}
    \noindent
    \raggedright
    \textit{#1}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\hsize}
    \noindent
    \raggedleft
    \textit{#2}
  \end{minipage}
}
\def\activities#1{
  \parbox{\hsize}{\vspace*{5pt}\raggedright\scriptsize #1}\smallskip
}

\let\@colbreak=&

\def\printdayname#1{\hfil\textsc{#1}\hfil}

\newcommand{\dayname}[1]{
  \ifnum#1=1 Sunday\else
  \ifnum#1=2 Monday\else
  \ifnum#1=3 Tuesday\else
  \ifnum#1=4 Wednesday\else
     \ifnum#1=5 Thursday\else
  \ifnum#1=6 Friday\else
  \ifnum#1=7 Saturday\else
    \PackageError{calendar}{Unrecognized day number: #1!}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}

\StartingDayNumber=1
\newenvironment{calendar}[1]{
  \newdimen\@calendarwidth
  \@calendarwidth=#1
  \begingroup
    \def\@calendarmode{\@CALtrue}
  \def\day##1##2{
  \if\@calendarmode\@CALtrue\else\PackageWarning{calendar}{The '\day' macro is expected to be used in the 'calendar' environment!}\fi
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum>7\global\@currentdaynum=1\fi
  \global\advance\@currentdaynum by 1
  \dayheader{##1}{\thecalendardate}\def\daysep{\vskip1pt\hrule\vskip1pt}
  \activities{##2}
  \addtocounter{calendardate}{1}
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum>7\@arraycr\hline\else&\fi
  }
\def\finishCalendar{
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=6 &\\\hline\else
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=5 &&\\\hline\else
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=4 &&&\\\hline\else
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=3 &&&&\\\hline\else
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=2 &&&&&\\\hline\else
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum=1 &&&&&&\\\hline
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
  \def\BlankDay{
  \if\@calendarmode\@CALtrue\else\PackageWarning{calendar}{The     '\calendarday' macro is expected to be used in the 'calendar' environment!}\fi
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum>7\global\@currentdaynum=1\fi
  \global\advance\@currentdaynum by 1
  \addtocounter{calendardate}{1}
  \ifnum\@currentdaynum>7\@arraycr\hline\else&\fi
  }

    \setcounter{calendardate}{1}
    \newcount\@currday
    \@currday=\StartingDayNumber
    \newcount\@numdays
    \@numdays=7
    \let\@cbreak=&
    \tabularx{\@calendarwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|} \hline

            \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}}     \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
    \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}}     \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
    \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}}     \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
    \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}} \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
    \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}} \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
    \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}} \global\advance\@currday by 1 &
   \ifnum\@currday>\@numdays\@currday=1\fi\printdayname{\dayname{\@currday}}     \global\advance\@currday by 1 \\ \hline \hline
      \@currentdaynum=1
      \let\@firstline=\@CALtrue
}{
    \endtabularx
  \endgroup
}
```

This is what I want, and see for that matter when looking at my preview in Overleaf.com

[image: What I want, Get in Latex]
This is what I get when trying to print without the "fit to page" option.

[image: What I get in the Printer dialogue]

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't compile (in texlive and on overleaf) `LaTeX Error: File calendar.sty not found.`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry for this, just added the code in the question

Comment: Are you sure that you use a4-paper in your pdf printer dialog?

Comment: What do you see when you export from OverLeaf to PDF? This is not the same as what you see in the preview. You have lots and lots and lots of spurious spaces. Maybe many of them don't matter; maybe not.

Comment: Please check code compiles before uploading. You at least need to end the `document` environment.

Comment: The code in `calendar.sty` is a bit odd. It includes error messages which will never be triggered, for example, because they apply to conditions when the error message itself is not defined. It will also be rather wasteful if more than one `calendar` environment is used in a document since everything has to be defined every time for no obvious reason. And it gives lots of bad boxes, but should print fine on A4.